# undefined reference to 'ASurfaceTexture_fromSurfaceTexture'

Tags: android, android-ndk, surface

I display image from camera and render it with opengl es and SurfaceTexture in native.but ASurfaceTexture_fromSurfaceTexture is undefined.I try every so in ndk library directory.
which .so should be linked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This API was added at platform level 28. This should be the **minSdkVersion** for your module.